# How do I find the difference between two dates in one query?

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql

i have a table in Mssql, in that table i have two columns that keeps different dates. (both data types are smalldatetime) my aim is , if difference is equal 60 days or bigger than 60 days then i want to bind this values into a grid view. How can i get this values in single sql query? Thanks for your help.

Comment: between two coloums, that i mention about in the text

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @KaanYurdakök I understand that, but difference of 60 days?, minutes?, months?, years?

Comment: ops, 60 days sorry about that

Answer (score 1):

Not a lot of information, so best guess looks like this:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(day, date1, date2) Difference, date1, date2
FROM aSecretTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, date1, date2) >= 60
```

Comment: can't we use "As" like select date_one,date_two from Table where (Select SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, date1, date2) Difference
FROM aSecretTable
WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR, date1, date2) > 60) as New_Table?

Comment: You could, or you could just add `, date1, date2` to the end of the `select` line. `WHERE (condition) as new_table` isn't going to be valid syntax. You should avoid putting sub-queries in where statements for performance reasons.

Comment: Updated the answer to reflect the added fields.